# Assigning values to a dictionary that come from 2 different files

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `bam.txt` file like that:

```
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
```

another file `bai.txt`:

```
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries which the keys are always like this:

```
keys = ['bam','bam_index']
d = dict.fromkeys(keys)
l = [d for x in range(3)]
print(l)

[{'bam': None, 'bam_index': None}, {'bam': None, 'bam_index': None}, {'bam': None, 'bam_index': None}]
```

Instead of values having `None` the dictionary should be like this:

```
[{'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}, {'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}, {'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}]
```

In words the first value of the first dictionary in the list of dictionaries must have the first line of the `bam.txt` , the second value of the first dictionary in the list must have the first line of `bai.txt` all the way till the end of the last line in both files.

I am aware `dict` values cannot be indexed since dictionaries are unordered data types in python, so perhaps this needs to be solved with `tuples` `generators` or `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over both the files line by line using `zip()` and prepare the dictionary as:

```
keys = ['bam','bam_index']
l = []
with open('bam.txt', 'r') as f1, open('bai.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for lf1, lf2 in zip(f1, f2):
        d = {keys[0] : lf1.strip(), keys[1] : lf2.strip()}
        l.append(d)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[{'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg001G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}, {'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg002G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}, {'bam': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bam', 'bam_index': 'exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg014G.GRCh38DH.target.bai'}]
```